# Airflow - CRITICAL - Cannot import authentication module airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth

Tags: airflow

I'm using `Airflow 1.9` and installed it using "`pip install apache-airflow[all]`". while trying to use LDAP authentication, I'm seeing the below error.

```
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: [2018-08-06 10:26:07,364] {__init__.py:64} CRITICAL - Cannot import authentication module airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth. Please correct your authentication backend or disable authentication: cannot import name NoValue
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: File "/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: args.func(args)
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 678, in webserver
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: app = cached_app(conf)
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 161, in cached_app
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: app = create_app(config)
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 44, in create_app
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: airflow.load_login()
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 67, in load_login
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: raise AirflowException("Failed to import authentication backend")
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow airflow: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Failed to import authentication backend
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow systemd: airflow-webserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow systemd: Unit airflow-webserver.service entered failed state.
Aug  6 10:26:07 test-airflow systemd: airflow-webserver.service failed.
```

Here is my `airflow.cfg`:

```
[webserver]
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth
base_url = http://test-airflow.example.com
```

Comment: That is a very small airflow.cfg According to the docs you also need a pretty big LDAP section: https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#ldap Where is base_url from? What docs did you use to setup LDAP auth?

Comment: Yeah I know, didn't add because I thought it was not necessary since the backend auth module itself is failing.

Comment: Ok, with this amount of information at least I cannot help and it seems no new information is added.

Answer (score 3):

I installed ldap3 to solve it.

```
pip install ldap3
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to your limited log entries, your issue might be a bit different, but this is what I found when I encountered this issue:

```
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: [2018-08-21 04:56:45,150] {__init__.py:64} CRITICAL - Cannot import authentication module airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth. Please correct your authentication backend or disable au
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 59, in load_login
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     login = import_module(auth_backend)
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py", line 23, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from ldap3 import Server, Connection, Tls, LEVEL, SUBTREE, BASE
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ldap3/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from .core.connection import Connection
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 37, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from ..extend import ExtendedOperationsRoot
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ldap3/extend/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from .standard.whoAmI import WhoAmI
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ldap3/extend/standard/whoAmI.py", line 27, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from pyasn1.type.univ import NoValue
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: ImportError: cannot import name 'NoValue'
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     args.func(args)
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 678, in webserver
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     app = cached_app(conf)
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 161, in cached_app
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     app = create_app(config)
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 44, in create_app
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     airflow.load_login()
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 67, in load_login
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     raise AirflowException("Failed to import authentication backend")
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Failed to import authentication backend
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 systemd[1]: airflow-webserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Note the following section:

```
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]:     from pyasn1.type.univ import NoValue
Aug 21 04:56:45 ip-10-202-21-240 airflow[10065]: ImportError: cannot import name 'NoValue'
```

It seems that the version of pyasn1 I had was old. Once I forced pip to download the latest version

```
sudo pip install pyasn1==0.4.4
```

That did the trick